# Inner class object

Tags: java, inner-classes

I couldn't understand the behavior of the below code.

My expectation was that it should print 100 in both `println()` methods. Why the result is different?

If I uncomment `getX()` method in inner class, then the output of `println(`) methods are the same which is 100.

I couldn't figure out the reasoning of different behavior. Please help me to understand.

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyOuter outerObj = new MyOuter();
        MyOuter.MyInner innerObj = outerObj.new MyInner();

        innerObj.setX();

        System.out.println("x: " + innerObj.getX()); //x: 3
        System.out.println("x: " + outerObj.getX()); //x: 100
    }
}
class MyOuter {
    private int x = 3;

    public int getX() { return x; }

    class MyInner extends MyOuter {
        public void setX(){ x = 100; }
//      public int getX() { return x; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `MyInner` has access to **two** different instances of the `MyOuter` class, one being the outer class, accessible using `MyOuter.this`, and one being the base class, accessible using `super`. `innerObj.getX()` calls the `getX()` method inherited from the base class. Seems the unqualified `x` accesses the `MyOuter.this` instance. For your code to make *any* sense, remove `extends Outer`.

Comment: *FYI:* I'm an experienced Java programmer, but if you had asked me whether an unqualified access would access the `super` instance or the `MyOuter.this` instance, I would have needed to consult the manual to answer that. Having the same class as both outer class and base class is just wrong, and should never happen in real life. If it did, the code should darn well always qualify field access, to ensure everybody understands what the code is doing. I would have preferred if the compiler would have failed with an "ambiguois access" error message.

Comment: @Andreas the behaviour is actually in-line with the [behaviour of `protected` in the context of a static method situated in a child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568031/why-protected-method-is-not-accessible-from-subclass).

Comment: @Turing85 LOL, we commented to each other at the same time. I missed the `private` part. --- *Curious:* Before today, would you have been able to answer whether unqualified access to `x` means `super.x` or `MyOuter.this.x` if the field hadn't been `private`?

Answer (score 4):

From `MyInner`'s perspective, there are two `private int x` fields in play here:

- One field `super.x` that is inherited from `MyOuter`, but inaccessible because it is declared as `private`, and `MyInner` as an inheriting object cannot access this field.
- One field `MyOuter.this.x` from the *sorrounding* `MyOuter`-instance (since `MyInner` is a (non-static) inner class, it is always bound to an instance of the surrounding `MyOuter`), that is accessible.

The method `setX()` in `MyInner` cannot access the inherited field `super.x`, thus it accesses the field `MyOuter.this.x` and sets its values to `100`. A consecutive call on the surrounding `MyOuter`'s `getX()` will return `100`.

The call `innerObj.getX()` (which is inherited from `MyOuter` and can access `super.x`) returns the value of the inherited field `super.x` (still having its initial value of `3`).

If we remove the `extends MyOuter` from and include the `getX()`-method in `MyInner`, the code behaves as expected.

---

The fact that `MyInner` cannot access the inherited field `private x` is confusing at first, but the behaviour is actually in line with the behaviour of the keyword `protected` in the context of static mehthods in inheriting classes as [discussed in this post by Hariharan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568031/why-protected-method-is-not-accessible-from-subclass)

Comment: Ahhh, `private`, I missed that detail, and that's why `x = 100` means `MyOuter.this.x = 100`, not `super.x = 100`. If you remove `private`, `x = 100` suddenly means `super.x = 100`. You might want to cover that in your answer too, for completeness. With ambiguity, `super` wins over outer class access, which does make sense, but still...

Comment: @Andreas ah I forgot the syntax of `MyOuter.this...`. Updated my answer. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: *Nitpick:* "nonstatic, inner class" --- Inner classes are [by definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) non-static: *"An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared `static`"*. --- But, reminding people is ok, so leave it... My OCD has been satisfied by this comment. ‍♂️

Comment: @Andreas I know ;) but especially in answers, I like to clarify the situation. Set it in parentheses :)